# Load panel by pressing a button

Tags: java, swing

I have two-panel class, PannelloM and PannelloM2.

Initially, I add to the JFrame an instance of PannelloM2.
I would like that when I press, "new .." is loaded on the JFrame PannelloM instead of the PannelloM2. How can I achieve this

The problem is that I have the button listeners inside the panel class, so I cannot add the panel itself to the frame.

Thank you

```
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.rmi.*;
import java.util.*;

 class ProvaMail{
 public static void main(String[] args){
  EmailMonitor em = new EmailMonitor();


  em.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  em.setVisible(true);
  }

  }

class EmailMonitor extends JFrame{
private PannelloM pannelloM;
private PannelloM2 pannelloM2;
public EmailMonitor(){
    ini();

    pannelloM= new PannelloM();
    pannelloM2= new PannelloM2();
    add(pannelloM2);
    }


    private void ini(){
   // prende la dimensione dello schermo
   Toolkit kit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
   Dimension screenSize = kit.getScreenSize();
   int screenHeight = screenSize.height;
  int screenWidth = screenSize.width;

  //centra il frame nello schermo
  setSize(screenWidth / 4, screenHeight / 2);
  setLocation(screenWidth / 4, screenHeight / 4);

  //imposta il titolo e il dimensionamento non automatico
  setTitle("Email Monitor");
  setResizable(false);
}
}


class PannelloM2 extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
private JPanel panel1;  
private JPanel panel4;  

JButton nuovo;
JButton leggi;
JButton elimina;

public PannelloM2(){
    iniP();
}

private void iniP(){

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JLabel label0 = new JLabel("Posta in arrivo:");
    panel1.add(label0, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(panel1, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    panel4 = new JPanel();
    panel4.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    nuovo = new JButton("Nuovo..");
    leggi = new JButton("Leggi..");
    elimina = new JButton("Elimina..");
    panel4.add(nuovo,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    panel4.add(leggi,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    panel4.add(elimina,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    add(panel4, BorderLayout.SOUTH);


    //registro i componenti al listener
    nuovo.addActionListener(this); 
    leggi.addActionListener(this); 
    elimina.addActionListener(this); 
}

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
    {
   String command = event.getActionCommand();

   if(command.equals("Nuovo..")) {  }

   else if(command.equals("Leggi..")) {

   }

   else if(command.equals("Elimina..")) {

   }
   }   
   }

   class PannelloM extends JPanel {
    private JPanel panel1; 
    private JPanel panel2; 
    private JPanel panel3; 
    private JPanel panel4;  
    private JPanel panel5;  


JButton arrivo; 
JButton rispondi; 
JButton rispondiTutti; 
JButton inoltra;

JButton after;  
JTextArea text1;
JTextField text2;
JTextField text3;


  public PannelloM(){
    iniP();
  }

   private void iniP(){
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JLabel label0 = new JLabel("Destinatari:");
    panel1.add(label0, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    text2 = new JTextField("",10);
    panel1.add(text2, BorderLayout.CENTER);


    panel2 = new JPanel();
    panel2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Oggetto:");
    panel2.add(label1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    text3 = new JTextField("",20);
    panel2.add(text3, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    panel1.add(panel2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    add(panel1, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    //imposto terzo pannello
    panel3 = new JPanel();
    panel3.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JLabel label3 = new JLabel("Testo:");
    panel3.add(label3, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    text1 = new JTextArea(5,20);

    panel3.add(text1, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    add(panel3, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    //imposto quarto pannello
    panel4 = new JPanel();
    panel4.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    arrivo = new JButton("Posta in arrivo..");
    rispondi = new JButton("Rispondi..");
    rispondiTutti = new JButton("Rispondi a tutti..");
    inoltra = new JButton("Inoltra..");
    panel4.add(arrivo,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    panel4.add(rispondi,BorderLayout.CENTER);

    //imposto quinto pannello dentro il panel 4
    panel5 = new JPanel();
    panel5.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    panel5.add(rispondiTutti,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    panel5.add(inoltra,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    panel4.add(panel5,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    add(panel4,BorderLayout.SOUTH);  

    //registro i componenti al listener
    arrivo.addActionListener(this);
    rispondi.addActionListener(this);
    rispondiTutti.addActionListener(this);
    inoltra.addActionListener(this);

    }


   }
```

Comment: 1) Use a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556). 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `ActionListener` from your Panels PannelloM and PannelloM2 and add the `ActionListener` inside `EmailMonitor`

```
public class EmailMonitor extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
```

Then implementing the abstract method `actionPerformed`
I would deal with changing the panel from `pannello2` to `panneloM`

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    String command = event.getActionCommand();

    if (command.equals("Nuovo..")) {
        this.setContentPane(pannelloM);
        this.invalidate();
        this.validate();


    } else if (command.equals("Leggi..")) {

    } else if (command.equals("Elimina..")) {

    }
}
```

**Connecting the button listeners to EmailMonitor**

I would create a reference to EmailMonitor on `PannelloM2` and `PannelloM` constructor

```
private EmailMonitor em;

public PannelloM2(EmailMonitor em) {
    this.em = em;
    iniP();
}
```

And

```
private EmailMonitor em;

public PannelloM(EmailMonitor em) {
    this.em = em;
    iniP();
}
```

Then you change your `addActionListeners` buttons inside your JPanels to reference `EmailMonitor`

```
//registro i componenti al listener
nuovo.addActionListener(em);
leggi.addActionListener(em);
elimina.addActionListener(em);
```

and

```
//registro i componenti al listener
arrivo.addActionListener(em);
rispondi.addActionListener(em);
rispondiTutti.addActionListener(em);
```

**EmailMonitor initialize your Panels like this**

```
public EmailMonitor() {
    ini();
    pannelloM = new PannelloM(this);
    pannelloM2 = new PannelloM2(this);
    add(pannelloM2);
}
```